# jhipster login difference between OAuth configuration and JWT configuration

Tags: authentication, jhipster

I am into JHipster recently and am so excited to use it and play around with it. I found that there is a difference between oauth and JWT configurations.

If I generate the app with JWT based authentication, it shows social login and remember me feature but Oauth based authentication doesn't. I attached the screen capture to see this.

Could anybody explain why this difference exists ?

[image: JWT based login]

[image: OAuth based login]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Social Login is an optional feature in JHipster.  It is only available with Session or JWT auth, and only with Monolithic apps.  It's not implemented for Oauth2 simply because no one has found the time ([issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2848)).

Remember Me is another feature that depends on the authentication type.

- For JWT, it means that the JWT token is stored in the browser's local storage (persisted) instead of session storage (temporary).  It also means the token lasts longer ([30 minutes vs 30 days](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/blob/faf2c74069ec7a1a90236b5a5bfe780698e2df69/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/JHipsterProperties.java#L504-L506)).
- For Oauth2, it doesn't mean anything so it wasn't added to the template for AngularJS.  The tokens are stored in "local storage" by default.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. It seems the best case could be when Oauth2 configuration would have included Social Login.